# Can you edit the title of an Area 51 proposal during the commitment stage?

Tags: discussion, area-51, edits, commitment-phase

...and if so, how? It has been suggested that I change [Managers and Leaders](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25641/managers-and-leaders) to "Management and Leadership," a change I agree with, but I'm not able to make the edit. I don't believe I have the appropriate Definition tools, and there's no "edit" button near the title or audience text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can flag your proposal for moderator attention. Leave a short message detailing why you would like the name changed and if a moderator finds it helpful he/she will change it for you.